# Adding resources to already existing stack by CF template on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops, pipeline, continuous-deployment

Is it possible to update aws stack by another CF template file while retaining resources which were present in original CF file used to create the stack initially, but not in current CF file used to update it?

I've looked into different api calls and stack files related stuff but no option comes to my mind working.

Answer (score 0):

> no option comes to my mind working

This is because, what you are asking for is **not possible**.